# Lucene index with multiple fields of the same nature

Tags: zend-framework, indexing, lucene

Each Lucene doc is a recipe, and each of these recipes have ingredients.

Im working towards being able to search the ingredients and give a result that says two ingredients matched out of four. (for example)

So how can I add the ingredients to the doc? In solr I can just create multiple fields of  and it would save them all, I might be doing something wrong because its only saving the one ingredient.

Also this would apply to a field like 'tags'.

p.s Im using the Zend Framework for this, if it matters at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lucene documents support the addition of multiple fields of the same name. i.e. you can repeatedly call:

```
document.add(new Field("name"), value)
```

So were you to do :

```
# (pseudo-code) 
document1.add(new Field("ingredient"), "vanilla") 
document1.add(new Field("ingredient"), "strawberry") 
index.add(document)

# And then search for
index.search("ingredient", "vanilla" && "strawberry")
```

You will get back document1. But if you search for:

```
index.search("ingredient", "vanilla" && "apple")
```

You will not get back **document1**.

If you searched for:

```
index.search("ingredient", "vanilla" || "apple")
```

You would also get back **document1**.

If you want to see which ingredients match you can simply save the fields on the document as **Stored** fields, and then for each matching document retrieve the list of fields and compare them to the user query.

Also note, by default the **PositionIncrementGap** for fields with the same name that are added to a document is 0.

This means that if you added:

```
   document1.add(new Field("ingredient"), "chocolate") 
   document1.add(new Field("ingredient"), "orange")
```

then it would be treated as if it were a single ingredient called "chocolate orange" which might match on :

```
index.search("ingredient", "chocolate orange")
```

You can avoid this set a value for PositionIncrementGap > 1, which will yield:

0 matches for:

```
index.search("ingredient", "chocolate orange")
```

and 1 match for:

```
index.search("ingredient", "chocolate" &&  "orange")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible approaches here:

1. Denormalize your data - create a separate document for each ingredient in a recipe, giving all of the documents for a recipe a common recipe id. Then, during search, aggregate all matches of a recipe id. A bit ugly.
2. Concatenate all your ingredients into a common field, and index it as 'Text'. Then search for ingredients using a boolean query with 'OR' (This is called 'Should' in Java Lucene terms, I do not know the PHP equivalent).

I suggest you try the second approach and see if it helps.